# Magento 2, don't show order

Tags: magento2.3.7

When I click in order (Sales > Orders), I have this message:

```
1 exception(s):
Exception #0 (Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException): Invalid method Magento\Sales\Block\Adminhtml\Order\AbstractOrder::helper
Exception #0 (Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException): Invalid method Magento\Sales\Block\Adminhtml\Order\AbstractOrder::helper
<pre>#1 include('/home/klient.dho...') called at [vendor/magento/framework/View/TemplateEngine/Php.php:59]
#2 Magento\Framework\View\TemplateEngine\Php->render(&Magento\Sales\Block\Adminhtml\Order\AbstractOrder#000000004270f81b000000003b4f6f51#, '/home/klient.dho...', array('csp' => &Magento\Csp\Helper\InlineUtil#000000004270fc10000000003b4f6f51#, 'escaper' => &Magento\Framework\Escaper#000000004270f73d000000003b4f6f51#)) called at [vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php:58]
#3 Magento\Framework\View\TemplateEngine\Php\Interceptor->___callParent('render', array(&Magento\Sales\Block\Adminhtml\Order\AbstractOrder#000000004270f81b000000003b4f6f51#, '/home/klient.dho...', array('csp' => &Magento\Csp\Helper\InlineUtil#000000004270fc10000000003b4f6f51#, 'escaper' => &Magento\Framework\Escaper#000000004270f73d000000003b4f6f51#))) called at [vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php:138]
#4 Magento\Framework\View\TemplateEngine\Php\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}(&Magento\Sales\Block\Adminhtml\Order\AbstractOrder#000000004270f81b000000003b4f6f51#, '/home/klient.dho...', array()) called at [vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php:153]
#5 Magento\Framework\View\TemplateEngine\Php\Interceptor->___callPlugins('render', array(&Magento\Sales\Block\Adminhtml\Order\AbstractOrder#000000004270f81b000000003b4f6f51#, '/home/klient.dho...', array()), array(array('csp_helper_plugi...', 'Olegnax_Core_Plu...'))) called at [generated/code/Magento/Framework/View/TemplateEngine/Php/Interceptor.php:26]
#6 Magento\Framework\View\TemplateEngine\Php\Interceptor->render(&Magento\Sales\Block\Adminhtml\Order\AbstractOrder#000000004270f81b000000003b4f6f51#, '/home/klient.dho...', array()) called at [vendor/magento/framework/View/Element/Template.php:271]
#7 Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template->fetchView('/home/klient.dho...') called at [vendor/magento/framework/View/Element/Template.php:301]
#8 Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template->_toHtml() called at [vendor/magento/module-backend/Block/Template.php:129]
#9 Magento\Backend\Block\Template->_toHtml() called at [vendor/magento/framework/View/Element/AbstractBlock.php:1100]
#10 Magento\Framework\View\Element\AbstractBlock->Magento\Framework\View\Element\{closure}() called at [vendor/magento/framework/View/Element/AbstractBlock.php:1104]
#11 Magento\Framework\View\Element\AbstractBlock->_loadCache() called at [vendor/magento/framework/View/Element/AbstractBlock.php:674]
#12 Magento\Framework\View\Element\AbstractBlock->toHtml() called at [vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php:566]
#13 Magento\Framework\View\Layout->_renderBlock('order_shipping_v...') called at [vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php:542]
#14 Magento\Framework\View\Layout->renderNonCachedElement('order_shipping_v...') called at [generated/code/Magento/Framework/View/Layout/Interceptor.php:206]
#15 Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->renderNonCachedElement('order_shipping_v...') called at [vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php:497]
#16 Magento\Framework\View\Layout->renderElement('order_shipping_v...', true) called at [generated/code/Magento/Framework/View/Layout/Interceptor.php:193]
#17 Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->renderElement('order_shipping_v...', true) called at [vendor/magento/framework/View/Element/AbstractBlock.php:521]
#18 Magento\Framework\View\Element\AbstractBlock->getChildHtml('order_shipping_v...') called at [vendor/magento/module-sales/view/adminhtml/templates/order/view/tab/info.phtml:37]
#19 include('/home/klient.dho...') called at [vendor/magento/framework/View/TemplateEngine/Php.php:59]
#20 Magento\Framework\View\TemplateEngine\Php->render(&Magento\Sales\Block\Adminhtml\Order\View\Tab\Info#000000004270f968000000003b4f6f51#, '/home/klient.dho...', array('csp' => &Magento\Csp\Helper\InlineUtil#000000004270fc10000000003b4f6f51#, 'escaper' => &Magento\Framework\Escaper#000000004270f73d000000003b4f6f51#)) called at [vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php:58]
#21 Magento\Framework\View\TemplateEngine\Php\Interceptor->___callParent('render', array(&Magento\Sales\Block\Adminhtml\Order\View\Tab\Info#000000004270f968000000003b4f6f51#, '/home/klient.dho...', array('csp' => &Magento\Csp\Helper\InlineUtil#000000004270fc10000000003b4f6f51#, 'escaper' => &Magento\Framework\Escaper#000000004270f73d000000003b4f6f51#))) called at [vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php:138]
#22 Magento\Framework\View\TemplateEngine\Php\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}(&Magento\Sales\Block\Adminhtml\Order\View\Tab\Info#000000004270f968000000003b4f6f51#, '/home/klient.dho...', array()) called at [vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php:153]
#23 Magento\Framework\View\TemplateEngine\Php\Interceptor->___callPlugins('render', array(&Magento\Sales\Block\Adminhtml\Order\View\Tab\Info#000000004270f968000000003b4f6f51#, '/home/klient.dho...', array()), array(array('csp_helper_plugi...', 'Olegnax_Core_Plu...'))) called at [generated/code/Magento/Framework/View/TemplateEngine/Php/Interceptor.php:26]
#24 Magento\Framework\View\TemplateEngine\Php\Interceptor->render(&Magento\Sales\Block\Adminhtml\Order\View\Tab\Info#000000004270f968000000003b4f6f51#, '/home/klient.dho...', array()) called at [vendor/magento/framework/View/Element/Template.php:271]
#25 Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template->fetchView('/home/klient.dho...') called at [vendor/magento/framework/View/Element/Template.php:301]
#26 Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template->_toHtml() called at [vendor/magento/module-backend/Block/Template.php:129]
#27 Magento\Backend\Block\Template->_toHtml() called at [vendor/magento/framework/View/Element/AbstractBlock.php:1100]
#28 Magento\Framework\View\Element\AbstractBlock->Magento\Framework\View\Element\{closure}() called at [vendor/magento/framework/View/Element/AbstractBlock.php:1104]
#29 Magento\Framework\View\Element\AbstractBlock->_loadCache() called at [vendor/magento/framework/View/Element/AbstractBlock.php:674]
#30 Magento\Framework\View\Element\AbstractBlock->toHtml() called at [vendor/magento/module-backend/Block/Widget/Tabs.php:492]
#31 Magento\Backend\Block\Widget\Tabs->getTabContent(&Magento\Sales\Block\Adminhtml\Order\View\Tab\Info#000000004270f968000000003b4f6f51#) called at [vendor/magento/module-backend/view/adminhtml/templates/widget/tabs.phtml:58]
#32 include('/home/klient.dho...') called at [vendor/magento/framework/View/TemplateEngine/Php.php:59]
#33 Magento\Framework\View\TemplateEngine\Php->render(&Magento\Sales\Block\Adminhtml\Order\View\Tabs#000000004270f988000000003b4f6f51#, '/home/klient.dho...', array('tabs' => array('order_info' => &Magento\Sales\Block\Adminhtml\Order\View\Tab\Info#000000004270f968000000003b4f6f51#, 'order_invoices' => &Magento\Sales\Block\Adminhtml\Order\View\Tab\Invoices#000000004270f860000000003b4f6f51#, 'order_creditmemo...' => &Magento\Sales\Block\Adminhtml\Order\View\Tab\Creditmemos#000000004270f862000000003b4f6f51#, 'order_shipments' => &Magento\Sales\Block\Adminhtml\Order\View\Tab\Shipments#000000004270f875000000003b4f6f51#, 'order_history' => &Magento\Sales\Block\Adminhtml\Order\View\Tab\History#000000004270fff0000000003b4f6f51#, 'order_transactio...' => &Magento\Sales\Block\Adminhtml\Order\View\Tab\Transactions#000000004270f989000000003b4f6f51#), 'csp' => &Magento\Csp\Helper\InlineUtil#000000004270fc10000000003b4f6f51#, 'escaper' => &Magento\Framework\Escaper#000000004270f73d000000003b4f6f51#)) called at [vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php:58]
#34 Magento\Framework\View\TemplateEngine\Php\Interceptor->___callParent('render', array(&Magento\Sales\Block\Adminhtml\Order\View\Tabs#000000004270f988000000003b4f6f51#, '/home/klient.dho...', array('tabs' => array('order_info' => &Magento\Sales\Block\Adminhtml\Order\View\Tab\Info#000000004270f968000000003b4f6f51#, 'order_invoices' => &Magento\Sales\Block\Adminhtml\Order\View\Tab\Invoices#000000004270f860000000003b4f6f51#, 'order_creditmemo...' => &Magento\Sales\Block\Adminhtml\Order\View\Tab\Creditmemos#000000004270f862000000003b4f6f51#, 'order_shipments' => &Magento\Sales\Block\Adminhtml\Order\View\Tab\Shipments#000000004270f875000000003b4f6f51#, 'order_history' => &Magento\Sales\Block\Adminhtml\Order\View\Tab\History#000000004270fff0000000003b4f6f51#, 'order_transactio...' => &Magento\Sales\Block\Adminhtml\Order\View\Tab\Transactions#000000004270f989000000003b4f6f51#), 'csp' => &Magento\Csp\Helper\InlineUtil#000000004270fc10000000003b4f6f51#, 'escaper' => &Magento\Framework\Escaper#000000004270f73d000000003b4f6f51#))) called at [vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php:138]
#35 Magento\Framework\View\TemplateEngine\Php\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}(&Magento\Sales\Block\Adminhtml\Order\View\Tabs#000000004270f988000000003b4f6f51#, '/home/klient.dho...', array('tabs' => array('order_info' => &Magento\Sales\Block\Adminhtml\Order\View\Tab\Info#000000004270f968000000003b4f6f51#, 'order_invoices' => &Magento\Sales\Block\Adminhtml\Order\View\Tab\Invoices#000000004270f860000000003b4f6f51#, 'order_creditmemo...' => &Magento\Sales\Block\Adminhtml\Order\View\Tab\Creditmemos#000000004270f862000000003b4f6f51#, 'order_shipments' => &Magento\Sales\Block\Adminhtml\Order\View\Tab\Shipments#000000004270f875000000003b4f6f51#, 'order_history' => &Magento\Sales\Block\Adminhtml\Order\View\Tab\History#000000004270fff0000000003b4f6f51#, 'order_transactio...' => &Magento\Sales\Block\Adminhtml\Order\View\Tab\Transactions#000000004270f989000000003b4f6f51#))) called at [vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php:153]
#36 Magento\Framework\View\TemplateEngine\Php\Interceptor->___callPlugins('render', array(&Magento\Sales\Block\Adminhtml\Order\View\Tabs#000000004270f988000000003b4f6f51#, '/home/klient.dho...', array('tabs' => array('order_info' => &Magento\Sales\Block\Adminhtml\Order\View\Tab\Info#000000004270f968000000003b4f6f51#, 'order_invoices' => &Magento\Sales\Block\Adminhtml\Order\View\Tab\Invoices#000000004270f860000000003b4f6f51#, 'order_creditmemo...' => &Magento\Sales\Block\Adminhtml\Order\View\Tab\Creditmemos#000000004270f862000000003b4f6f51#, 'order_shipments' => &Magento\Sales\Block\Adminhtml\Order\View\Tab\Shipments#000000004270f875000000003b4f6f51#, 'order_history' => &Magento\Sales\Block\Adminhtml\Order\View\Tab\History#000000004270fff0000000003b4f6f51#, 'order_transactio...' => &Magento\Sales\Block\Adminhtml\Order\View\Tab\Transactions#000000004270f989000000003b4f6f51#))), array(array('csp_helper_plugi...', 'Olegnax_Core_Plu...'))) called at [generated/code/Magento/Framework/View/TemplateEngine/Php/Interceptor.php:26]
#37 Magento\Framework\View\TemplateEngine\Php\Interceptor->render(&Magento\Sales\Block\Adminhtml\Order\View\Tabs#000000004270f988000000003b4f6f51#, '/home/klient.dho...', array('tabs' => array('order_info' => &Magento\Sales\Block\Adminhtml\Order\View\Tab\Info#000000004270f968000000003b4f6f51#, 'order_invoices' => &Magento\Sales\Block\Adminhtml\Order\View\Tab\Invoices#000000004270f860000000003b4f6f51#, 'order_creditmemo...' => &Magento\Sales\Block\Adminhtml\Order\View\Tab\Creditmemos#000000004270f862000000003b4f6f51#, 'order_shipments' => &Magento\Sales\Block\Adminhtml\Order\View\Tab\Shipments#000000004270f875000000003b4f6f51#, 'order_history' => &Magento\Sales\Block\Adminhtml\Order\View\Tab\History#000000004270fff0000000003b4f6f51#, 'order_transactio...' => &Magento\Sales\Block\Adminhtml\Order\View\Tab\Transactions#000000004270f989000000003b4f6f51#))) called at [vendor/magento/framework/View/Element/Template.php:271]
#38 Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template->fetchView('/home/klient.dho...') called at [vendor/magento/framework/View/Element/Template.php:301]
#39 Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template->_toHtml() called at [vendor/magento/module-backend/Block/Template.php:129]
#40 Magento\Backend\Block\Template->_toHtml() called at [vendor/magento/framework/View/Element/AbstractBlock.php:1100]
#41 Magento\Framework\View\Element\AbstractBlock->Magento\Framework\View\Element\{closure}() called at [vendor/magento/framework/View/Element/AbstractBlock.php:1104]
#42 Magento\Framework\View\Element\AbstractBlock->_loadCache() called at [vendor/magento/framework/View/Element/AbstractBlock.php:674]
#43 Magento\Framework\View\Element\AbstractBlock->toHtml() called at [vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php:566]
#44 Magento\Framework\View\Layout->_renderBlock('sales_order_tabs') called at [vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php:542]
#45 Magento\Framework\View\Layout->renderNonCachedElement('sales_order_tabs') called at [generated/code/Magento/Framework/View/Layout/Interceptor.php:206]
#46 Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->renderNonCachedElement('sales_order_tabs') called at [vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php:497]
#47 Magento\Framework\View\Layout->renderElement('sales_order_tabs', false) called at [generated/code/Magento/Framework/View/Layout/Interceptor.php:193]
#48 Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->renderElement('sales_order_tabs', false) called at [vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php:594]
#49 Magento\Framework\View\Layout->_renderContainer('left', false) called at [vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php:544]
#50 Magento\Framework\View\Layout->renderNonCachedElement('left') called at [generated/code/Magento/Framework/View/Layout/Interceptor.php:206]
#51 Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->renderNonCachedElement('left') called at [vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php:497]
#52 Magento\Framework\View\Layout->renderElement('left', false) called at [generated/code/Magento/Framework/View/Layout/Interceptor.php:193]
#53 Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->renderElement('left', false) called at [vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php:594]
#54 Magento\Framework\View\Layout->_renderContainer('side.col', false) called at [vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php:544]
#55 Magento\Framework\View\Layout->renderNonCachedElement('side.col') called at [generated/code/Magento/Framework/View/Layout/Interceptor.php:206]
#56 Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->renderNonCachedElement('side.col') called at [vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php:497]
#57 Magento\Framework\View\Layout->renderElement('side.col', false) called at [generated/code/Magento/Framework/View/Layout/Interceptor.php:193]
#58 Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->renderElement('side.col', false) called at [vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php:594]
#59 Magento\Framework\View\Layout->_renderContainer('page.main.contai...', false) called at [vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php:544]
#60 Magento\Framework\View\Layout->renderNonCachedElement('page.main.contai...') called at [generated/code/Magento/Framework/View/Layout/Interceptor.php:206]
#61 Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->renderNonCachedElement('page.main.contai...') called at [vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php:497]
#62 Magento\Framework\View\Layout->renderElement('page.main.contai...', false) called at [generated/code/Magento/Framework/View/Layout/Interceptor.php:193]
#63 Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->renderElement('page.main.contai...', false) called at [vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php:594]
#64 Magento\Framework\View\Layout->_renderContainer('page.content', false) called at [vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php:544]
#65 Magento\Framework\View\Layout->renderNonCachedElement('page.content') called at [generated/code/Magento/Framework/View/Layout/Interceptor.php:206]
#66 Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->renderNonCachedElement('page.content') called at [vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php:497]
#67 Magento\Framework\View\Layout->renderElement('page.content', false) called at [generated/code/Magento/Framework/View/Layout/Interceptor.php:193]
#68 Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->renderElement('page.content', false) called at [vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php:594]
#69 Magento\Framework\View\Layout->_renderContainer('page.wrapper', false) called at [vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php:544]
#70 Magento\Framework\View\Layout->renderNonCachedElement('page.wrapper') called at [generated/code/Magento/Framework/View/Layout/Interceptor.php:206]
#71 Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->renderNonCachedElement('page.wrapper') called at [vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php:497]
#72 Magento\Framework\View\Layout->renderElement('page.wrapper', false) called at [generated/code/Magento/Framework/View/Layout/Interceptor.php:193]
#73 Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->renderElement('page.wrapper', false) called at [vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php:594]
#74 Magento\Framework\View\Layout->_renderContainer('backend.page', false) called at [vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php:544]
#75 Magento\Framework\View\Layout->renderNonCachedElement('backend.page') called at [generated/code/Magento/Framework/View/Layout/Interceptor.php:206]
#76 Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->renderNonCachedElement('backend.page') called at [vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php:497]
#77 Magento\Framework\View\Layout->renderElement('backend.page', false) called at [generated/code/Magento/Framework/View/Layout/Interceptor.php:193]
#78 Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->renderElement('backend.page', false) called at [vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php:594]
#79 Magento\Framework\View\Layout->_renderContainer('root', false) called at [vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php:544]
#80 Magento\Framework\View\Layout->renderNonCachedElement('root') called at [generated/code/Magento/Framework/View/Layout/Interceptor.php:206]
#81 Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->renderNonCachedElement('root') called at [vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php:497]
#82 Magento\Framework\View\Layout->renderElement('root', true) called at [generated/code/Magento/Framework/View/Layout/Interceptor.php:193]
#83 Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->renderElement('root') called at [vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php:963]
#84 Magento\Framework\View\Layout->getOutput() called at [generated/code/Magento/Framework/View/Layout/Interceptor.php:492]
#85 Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->getOutput() called at [vendor/magento/framework/View/Result/Page.php:258]
#86 Magento\Framework\View\Result\Page->render(&Magento\Framework\App\Response\Http\Interceptor#000000004270f4ea000000003b4f6f51#) called at [vendor/magento/framework/View/Result/Layout.php:171]
#87 Magento\Framework\View\Result\Layout->renderResult(&Magento\Framework\App\Response\Http\Interceptor#000000004270f4ea000000003b4f6f51#) called at [generated/code/Magento/Backend/Model/View/Result/Page/Interceptor.php:193]
#88 Magento\Backend\Model\View\Result\Page\Interceptor->renderResult(&Magento\Framework\App\Response\Http\Interceptor#000000004270f4ea000000003b4f6f51#) called at [vendor/magento/framework/App/Http.php:120]
#89 Magento\Framework\App\Http->launch() called at [generated/code/Magento/Framework/App/Http/Interceptor.php:24]
#90 Magento\Framework\App\Http\Interceptor->launch() called at [vendor/magento/framework/App/Bootstrap.php:261]
#91 Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap->run(&Magento\Framework\App\Http\Interceptor#000000004270f4f3000000003b4f6f51#) called at [index.php:39]
</pre>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
php bin/magento setup:upgrade
php bin/magento setup:di:compile
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f
php bin/magento cache:flush
sudo chmod -R 777 generated/ pub/ var/
```

Hope this will work for you :)